# Facebook aggregation doesn't come up on my timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-timeline, facebook-opengraph

This is a very general question.
I am triggering few open graph actions from my facebook app, but the aggregation which I created in my settings doesn't show up on my timeline.Everything else works fine, i.e the ticker, news feed and activity log get updated after I trigger the action. The aggregation shows up in the application activity but not on my timeline. What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

First, Have you defined aggregations in the developer console?[image]

As per the doc [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-units/)

When a user installs an application that publishes back to Open Graph, an Aggregation defined by the application will appear on the user's Timeline based on two key factors:

- Data availability - Sufficient actions and objects were published to
  generate an Aggregation in a given time period.
- Feedback - Calculated based on how engaged users are with the
  Aggregation on their Timelines, covering both positive actions
  (liking, commenting, pinning) and negative ones (removing/hiding the
  aggregation, removing the application that generated the
  aggregation).

Comment: Yes, I have. The aggregations are showing up in the activity log of the application, but not on my timeline.

Comment: It shows when it find's the enough content to display as per the documentation "Data availability" section.